# I am trying to inject a service into a constructor using ASP.Net Dependency Injection but getting a message that my blank constructor is not enough

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Here is what I have so far.  I am trying to create a new ThemeManagementViewModel and inject into that a resource service using:

**Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection version 5.0.1 nuget package**

```
public static class Startup
{
  public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
  public static IServiceProvider Init()
  {
     var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().ConfigureServices()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
     ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
     return serviceProvider;
  }
}

 public static class DependencyInjectionContainer
 {
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IResourceService, ResourceService>();
        services.AddTransient<ThemeManagementViewModel>();
        return services;
    }
 }

 public partial class ThemeManagementViewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
    private readonly IResourceService _resourceService;
    public ThemeManagementViewModel(IResourceService resourceService)
    {
        _resourceService = resourceService;
    }
 }

 public partial class ResourceService : IResourceService
 {
    private IDatabaseService _databaseService;
    public ResourceService(IDatabaseService databaseService)
    {
        _databaseService = databaseService;
    }
 }

 public interface IResourceService
 {
    void SetResourceColors();
 }


 public class ThemeManagementPage : HeadingView
 {
  private readonly ThemeManagementViewModel _vm;
  public ThemeManagementPage()
  {
     BindingContext  = _vm = new ThemeManagementViewModel();
  }
 }
```

When I build my application it gives me a message for this line:

```
BindingContext  = _vm = new ThemeManagementViewModel();
```

and this is the message that I am getting.

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required 
formal parameter 'resourceService' of 
'ThemeManagementViewModel.ThemeManagementViewModel(IResourceService)'
```

I thought that the DI was supposed to insert the service into the constructor of `ThemeManagementViewModel` but it seems not to be working.

Comment: I thinky you get the compiler error for some code you haven't shown here. Please show the part of the code that actually produces the error message. Also: It seems a bit weird to derive a service class from BaseViewModel. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Thanks very much.  I missed out that file and have now added it.  I am trying to provide my ThemeViewModel with a IResourceService.

Comment: Using `new` you don't use `DependencyInjectionContainer`.

Comment: My BaseViewModel is very simple and nothing more than just this: public class BaseViewModel : MvvmHelpers.BaseViewModel { public BaseViewModel() { } }  Where MvvmHelpers is a nuget package library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency injection will not simply take place anywhere where you construct an object. You need to go explicitly through your DI framework.

In this case, you need to call [`GetRequiredService()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice) of your `IServiceProvider` object.

```
var _vm = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ThemeManagementViewModel>();
```

Also, from your code, we don't see that you use your `DependencyInjectionContainer` class at all. You must make sure that your `ConfigureServices` method is called explicitly.

---

DI cannot do magic. The compiler doesn't know anything about it. You have to use it explicitly. It looks like it could do magic in the context of ASP.net website projects. But that is only because there it is the ASP.net framework that handles the things that you need to do explicitly in other types of projects.

---

- [Tutorial on how to use DI in .net applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage)